# Wondering how to add arrays of vectors?

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I need to add two vectors in the arrays together. For example my code should execute the vector = {3,6,9}.
I dont really know what I did wrong as I am still new to coding. So any help is appreciated!

```
void add_vectors( double vector1[3]={1,2,3},double vector2[3]={1,2,3},double
 vector3[3]={1,2,3}, int n)

{

    n=sizeof(vector1);

    int i;

    for(i=0; i>n; i++)

    {

    scanf("%f", &vector1[i]); 

    scanf("%f", &vector2[i]);

    vector3[i]=vector1[i]+vector2[i];

    }

    printf (vector3[]);
```

Sorry for the bad formatting but it's my frist time using this site.

Comment: It should be i < n, otherwise the code never enters the loop

Comment: Please read http://www.sscce.org/, and read [_How do I ask a good question?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use `%lf` for `double`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/bGwHQt

Answer (score 2):

There are several mistakes here in the code:

First, sizeof() gives you a size of something in a memory (in bytes), which is probably not what you desire.

Secondly, i>n statement means that the loops will execute only while i > n! The first time i = 0, and n is a positive integer. That means that the loop will be skipped, since i is not larger than n.

Third, printf() does not work like this.

I explained you the second point; my first and third points are widely explained on the internet: try finding these answers yourself.